# find the quotient space $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})$, upto isomoprhism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all matrices whose trace is zero. How do I

> find the quotient space
>   $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})$, upto isomoprhism?

As much as I have understood $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and as for any matrix in $\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})$, the one of the diagonal element will be determined by the sum of the rest of the diagonal elements, $\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}^{n^2-1}$. Hence the quotient space $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}^{n^2}/\mathbb{R}^{n^2-1}\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Have I done it right?

Comment: For real vector spaces $U\subseteq V$, it is true that $V/U \cong \mathbb{R}^{\dim V - \dim U}$.  However, in many ways - it's better to approach it as Matthew did in his answer.  Specifically, if $U$ and $V$ stand for other things (groups, rings, fields), then $V/U$ depends not just on $V$ and $U$, but also on how $U$ sits inside of $V$.

Comment: Yes, Matthew's method is much more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by “find”, but yes, the quotient space is one-dimensional.

The trace itself is a linear map from your $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})$ onto $\mathbb{R}$.  Its kernel or nullspace is, by definition, $\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R})$.  So by the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem_3),
$$
    \mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{T}(n;\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}
$$